# Allgemeine Hochschulreife vs. allgemeine Hochschulreife

Tags: capitalization

Das Abitur ist die Bestätigung der allgemeinen Hochschulreife – oder der **A**llgemeinen Hochschulreife? Auf Wikipedia und dem einzigen Duden-Eintrag, den ich finden konnte, wird das Adjektiv kleingeschrieben. Allerdings erinnert die Verwendung dieses Konstrukts eher an einen feststehenden Begriff, den man eben großschreiben würde. Wenn ich [a/A]llgemeine Hochschulreife schreibe, meine ich damit die fachsprachliche Ausformulierung von „Abitur“, möchte also nicht die erworbene Hochschulreife näher beschreiben (als allgemein, in Abgrenzung zu einer spezifischen Hochschulreife).

Gibt es hierzu eine Regel? Wird es groß- oder kleingeschrieben?

Comment: Die Überschrift ergibt keinen Sinn.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Diese Antwort ist durch die Änderung der deutschen Rechtschreibregeln am 29.06.2017 betroffen und daher nicht mehr auf dem aktuellsten Stand.*

Ich sehe hier zwei Rechtschreibregeln, die man für die Großschreibung von *allgemeine* anführen könnte (eine Kleinschreibung scheint mir auf jeden Fall akzeptabel):

> **§ 63 E**: Bei Verbindungen mit einer neuen, idiomatisierten Gesamtbedeutung kann der Schreibende zur Hervorhebung dieses besonderen Gebrauchs das Adjektiv großschreiben, zum Beispiel:
>
> *das Schwarze Brett* (= Anschlagtafel), *der Weiße Tod* (= Lawinentod)
>
> Kleinschreibung des Adjektivs ist in diesen Fällen der Regelfall.

Die neue idiomatisierte Gesamtbedeutung wäre hier die Qualifikation, die z. B. das Abitur beinhaltet. Und dass diese Gesamtbedeutung eine andere ist, also mehr (oder weniger) ist als die Summe der Einzelbedeutungen, ist durchaus eine vertretbare Position.

Oder umgedreht gesehen: Genauso wie ein Schwarzes Brett nicht wirklich schwarz sein muss, kann man die Allgemeine Hochschulreife, wie sie vom Abitur verliehen wird, als nicht wirklich allgemein ansehen. Hier kann man zwei Sichtweisen fahren:

- *Hochschulreife* ist bereits mehr als die Summe ihrer Teile (und damit idiomatisiert), da nicht jeder Mensch mit Hochschulreife reif für die Hochschule ist, und hat die zusätzliche Bedeutung *Universitätsqualifikation.* Aber nur weil *Hochschulreife* idiomatisiert ist, muss es *Allgemeine Hochschulreife* noch nicht sein. Letzteres kommt erst dadurch, dass die *Allgemeine Hochschulreife* eben keine *allgemeine Universitätszulassung* ist, sondern höchstens im Sinne des deutschen Bildungssystems. Zum Beispiel kann mich eine amerikanische Universität einen trotz Allgemeiner Hochschulreife ablehnen.
- *Hochschulreife* ist nicht idiomatisiert, also nicht die Summe seiner Teile. Dann ist *Allgemeine Hochschulreife* aber erst recht idiomatisiert, da jemand der sie hat, eben nicht allgemein reif für die Hochschule ist.

> **§ 64 E**: Die Großschreibung von Adjektiven, die mit dem Substantiv zusammen für eine begriffliche Einheit stehen, ist auch […] bei Verbindungen mit terminologischem Charakter belegt, zum Beispiel:
>
> *Gelbe Karte, Goldener Schnitt, Kleine Anfrage; Erste Hilfe*

In Sinne dieser Regel ist *Allgemeine Hochschulreife* ein juristischer oder verwaltungstechnischer Terminus und hiernach großschreibbar.

Comment: Zwei gute Argumente, klingt überzeugend. Danke! :)

Comment: @Gin-San zwei Nichtargumente meines Erachtens; siehe meine konkurrierende Antwort.

Comment: @Jan Danke für die gute Gegendarstellung!

Comment: Natürlich kommt die allgemeine Hochschulreife in ihrer bekanntesten Form nur im deutschen Schul- und Universitätssystem vor, das weder allgemein gültig ist noch in anderen Ländern äquivalent gehandhabt wird. Aber mit dieser Argumentation müsste jede Kombination, die unter diesem Namen nur in Deutschland existiert, ein großgeschriebenes Adjektiv bekommen. Aber wie läse sich denn ein Vorläufiges amtliches Endergebnis?

Comment: @Jan: Meine Argumentation war nicht, dass es die allgemeine Hochschulreife nur in Deutschland gibt (und eventuell nicht mal dort – was ist mit Privathochschulen?), sondern dass die Allgemeinheit nur in Deutschland gilt und daher keine wirkliche Allgemeinheit ist. Ein vorläufiges amtliches Endergebnis ist hingegen wirklich vorläufig.

Comment: Dem könnte man widersprechen, indem man anführt, dass die englischen *A-Levels* auch zum Studium an allen englischen Universitäten berechtigt, aber nicht notwendigerweise an kontinentaleuropäischen. Auch Finnland scheint mit dem *ylioppilastutkinto* eine allgemeine Hochschulzugangsberechtigung zu kennen. Das spräche dann eher dafür, die *fachgebundene* Hochschulreife großzuschreiben, weil die etwas spezieller-deutsches sei? Das Konzept sowohl der Hochschulreife wie auch der Allgemeinheit sind aber auch in anderen Ländern bekannt.

Answer (score 4):

Ich möchte Wrzlprmfts Einschätzung widersprechen.

Die allgemeine Hochschulreife setzt sich von der *fachgebundenen* Hochschulreife ab, die zum Beispiel an einer Berufsoberschule, einer Fachoberschule (an der man in Bayern auch die allgemeine Hochschulreife erwerben kann) oder an Fachgymnasien erworben werden kann.

Die fachgebundene Hochschulreife berechtigt, wie der Name vermuten lässt, nur zum Studium bestimmter Fächer oder Fächerkombinationen. Die allgemeine Hochschulreife berechtigt zum Studium *aller* Hochschulfächer.

Zur Zulassung zu einem Studium wird nur *eine* Hochschulreife verlangt; im Falle der fachgebundenen muss sie aber mit dem Studienfach übereinstimmen.

Da also **das Ganze nicht mehr als die Summer seiner Teile ist,** ist das *allgemein* der Hochschulreife **in jedem Fall kleinzuschreiben!**

Dass hier nur zwei mögliche Adjektive zur Beschreibung der Hochschulreife auftreten, sollte kein Hindernis sein; niemand würde auf die Idee kommen, den beschrankten und den unbeschrankten Bahnübergang (die gemeinsam alle möglichen Bahnübergänge einschließen) großzuschreiben.

---

Die Kleinschreibung der Adjektive *fachgebunden* und *allgemein* wird im Übrigen sowohl vom Bayerischen Gesetz über das Erziehungs- und Unterrichtswesen (BayEUG; insbesondere [Artikel 9](http://www.gesetze-bayern.de/jportal/portal/page/bsbayprod.psml?nid=g&showdoccase=1&doc.id=jlr-EUGBY2000V32Art9&st=null) (Gymnasium)<sup>[1]</sup> und [Artikel 16](http://www.gesetze-bayern.de/jportal/portal/page/bsbayprod.psml?nid=o&showdoccase=1&doc.id=jlr-EUGBY2000V24Art16&st=null) (Fachoberschule)<sup>[2]</sup>) als auch von der Schulordnung für die Gymnasien in Bayern (GSO; insbesondere §§ [85](http://www.gesetze-bayern.de/jportal/portal/page/bsbayprod.psml?nid=3w&showdoccase=1&doc.id=jlr-GymSchulOBY2007V8P85&st=null) und [86](http://www.gesetze-bayern.de/jportal/portal/page/bsbayprod.psml?nid=3y&showdoccase=1&doc.id=jlr-GymSchulOBY2007V8P86&st=null)<sup>[3]</sup>) verwendet.

---

---

Quellen (alle Hervorhebungen von mir):

[1]: Absatz 2: Das Gymnasium umfasst die Jahrgangsstufen 5 bis 12. Es baut auf der Grundschule auf, schließt mit der Abiturprüfung ab und verleiht die **allgemeine Hochschulreife.**

[2]: Absatz 2, Sätze 5 bis 6: Für überdurchschnittlich qualifizierte Absolventen der Fachabiturprüfung kann eine Jahrgangsstufe 13 geführt werden. Diese verleiht nach bestandener Abiturprüfung die **fachgebundene Hochschulreife** sowie bei Nachweis der notwendigen Kenntnisse in einer zweiten Fremdsprache die **allgemeine Hochschulreife.**

[3]: Zum Beispiel § 85, Absatz 1: Die **allgemeine Hochschulreife** wird der Schülerin oder dem Schüler zuerkannt, wenn

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort diesbezüglich ausführlicher gemacht. Außerdem legen Deine Ausführungen meines Erachtens nur da, dass die Bezeichnung *allgemeine Hochschulreife* nicht von irgendwoher kommt, aber nicht dass sie nur die Summe seiner Teile ist. Ähnliche Argumente treffen auch auf *Gelbe Karte* zu, und das ist ein Beispiel der Rechtschreibregeln.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Eine gelbe Karte ist eine Karte (ob Spiel- oder Post-) in gelber Farbe. Eine Gelbe Karte ist gleichzeitig eine Verwarnung, also deutlich mehr.

Answer (score 3):

Die neuen Rechtschreibregeln vom 29.7.2017 legen fest, dass in *fachsprachlich oder terminologisch gebrauchten Verbindungen* das Adjektiv großschreibbar ist(*). Als Beispiel wird die "m/Mittlere Reife" gebracht.

*fachsprachlich oder terminologisch gebrauchte Verbindung* trifft meiner Meinung nach voll auf die "[aA]llgemeine Hochschulreife" zu (Außerhalb der Fachsprachlichkeit "Schulpolitik in der Bundesrepublik Deutschland" heißt das nämlich "Abitur" oder "Matura").

(*)Als Ergänzung nennt der Rechtschreibrat aber ein Schlupfloch, das sagt

> E2: Von der Möglichkeit, großzuschreiben, wird nicht in allen Fachsprachen Gebrauch gemacht. Zu Beispielen mit ausschließlicher Kleinschreibung siehe das Wörterverzeichnis.

Anmerkung von mir: der Begriff "[aA]llgemeine Hochschulreife" taucht nicht im Wörterverzeichnis auf, man enthält sich also einer Festlegung.

Die Ergänzung E2 sagt damit relativ klar, "wenn die Fachsprache nicht von der Möglichkeit der Großschreibung Gebrauch macht, schreibt man eben nicht groß"

Die Definition der "Fachsprache" dürfte hiermit den Kultusministerien der Länder überlassen sein, die die Gesetze formulieren, aus denen sich die Fachsprache definiert. Diese Gesetze scheinen vorwiegend Kleinschreibung des Adjektivs zu bevorzugen (**), daher wäre

> allgemeine Hochschulreife

wohl richtig.

Diese Aussage scheint der Antwort von Martin Rosenau recht zu geben - Wichtig ist hier aber der Begriff "Fachsprache" - Nur hierfür gestehe ich den Kultusministerien Kompetenz zu. Martin schreibt allgemeiner

> In Deutschland sind die Bundesländer diejenigen, die entscheiden, was "korrekte Rechtschreibung" ist.

Das halte ich in dieser Generalität für sachlich falsch.

(**) Eine kurze Web-Stichprobe bei den Internet-Auftritten der Kultusministerien der Länder hat folgendes ergeben:

- Baden-Württemberg: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Bayern: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Hessen: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Berlin:  *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Niedersachsen: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Mecklenburg-Vorpommern: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Sachsen-Anhalt: *Allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Sachsen: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- NRW: *allgemeine Hochschulreife*
- Rheinland-Pfalz:*allgemeine Hochschulreife*

Um die Sache vollends zu verwirren, scheint der Internet-Auftritt der *Kultusministerkonferenz der Länder* (der allerdings nicht sehr aktuell ist) grundsätzlich Großschreibung zu bevorzugen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich selbst habe in dieser Frage einen eher pragmatischen Ansatz, der sich an folgender Aussage Jans (gekürzt) orientiert:

> Die Kleinschreibung wird vom Schulgesetz verwendet.

In Deutschland sind die Bundesländer diejenigen, die das Recht haben, zu entscheiden, was "korrekte Rechtschreibung" ist.

Meines Wissens hat der Rechtschreibrat von den Ländern die Aufgabe bekommen, Vorschläge zu machen, die dann aber von den Bundesländern genehmigt werden müssen aber auch abgelehnt werden können. (Dadurch kam es bereits vor, dass nicht in allen Bundesländern dieselbe Rechtschreibung galt: Schleswig-Holstein 1998-1999.)

Aus diesem Grund bin ich der Meinung, dass die Schreibweise eines Begriffs, die von den Bundesländern in offiziellen Dokumenten verwendet wird, prinzipiell als korrekt anzusehen ist.

Der Begriff "allgemeine Hochschulreife" wird offensichtlich in den Dokumenten der meisten Bundesländer mit einem kleinen "a" geschrieben.

Was Rechtschreibregeln angeht:

Es gibt auch Begriffe, bei denen die korrekte Schreibweise eine Ausnahme von den gültigen Rechtschreibregeln darstellt. (In der alten Rechtschreibung z.B. "Stengel" und "radfahren".) Daher kann man bei feststehenden Begriffen nicht unbedingt mit Rechtschreibregeln argumentieren.

Comment: Die Aussage *In Deutschland sind die Bundesländer diejenigen, die entscheiden, was "korrekte Rechtschreibung" ist.* halte ich in dieser Generalität für sachlich falsch. Für die gesamte deutsche Sprache ist der Rechtschreibrat zuständig, an den man die Hoheit über die "gesamte deutsche Sprache" abgetreten hat, für die "Fachsprache deutsches Erziehungswesen" allerdings die Kultusministerien der Länder (weswegen ich ihnen die Hoheit über die Schreibweise von "allgemeiner Hochschulreife" zugestehen würde). Sonst bin ich größtenteils bei dir.

Comment: @tofro Ich habe meine Antwort etwas klarer formuliert.