# Schreibt man aufeinanderfolgende substantivierte Adjektive alle groß?

Tags: capitalization

Bei substantivierten Adjektiven schreibt man gewöhnlich das Adjektiv groß, z.B:

> Ich habe die zwei Burschen hier gesehen, der *Jüngere* war aber nicht lange da.

Wie ist es wenn wir mehrere Adjektive verwenden? Schreibt man dann alle groß, oder nur das letzte? Ich habe beide Schreibweisen gesehen, was ist aber richtig?

> Sie hatte auf die Reise mehrere Kleider mitgebracht, und das *Kleine Schwarze* würde sie auf dem Galaabend verwenden.

oder

> Sie hatte auf die Reise mehrere Kleider mitgebracht, und die *kleine Schwarze* würde sie auf dem Galaabend verwenden.

Comment: Steckt eine Absicht hinter "_die_ kleine Schwarze", gegenüber dem üblicheren _das_ kleine Schwarze? Ansonsten evtl. hilfreich: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/25053/1779

Comment: @moooeeeep  keine Absicht, nur fehlgeschrieben, was jetzt korrigiert Worden ist.

Comment: Das Problem bei dieser Frage ist, dass "das kleine Schwarze" als Bezeichnung für ein Kleidungsstück zu stark lexikalisiert ist. Das lenkt von der eigentlichen Frage ab. Wir sollten es probieren mit anderen Wörtern, zum Beispiel: Kellnerin bringt ein Tablett mit Bieren an den Tisch: "Wer bekommt das kleine Helle, wer bekommt das große Helle?" Hier würdest du dich kaum fragen, ob "große" großzuschreiben wäre.

Comment: Zur Einleitung der Frage: Ich habe (jetzt nicht die Zeit, es nachzuprüfen, aber auch) das dumme Gefühl, dass es heißen sollte: *Ich habe die zwei Burschen hier gesehen, der jüngere (! klein!) war aber nicht lange da.* Grund: die *Burschen* sind ja noch im Sinne, und es ist klar, dass *der jüngere* hier einer der vorerwähnten Burschen ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ich habe die zwei Burschen hier gesehen, der **J**üngere war aber nicht lange da.

Wenn in diesem Satz nur von zwei Personen die Rede ist, hätte man zumindest vor der Rechtschreibreform das Wort "jünger" hier klein geschrieben, da sich das Adjektiv auf das Wort "Burschen" bezieht. Ich gehe davon aus, dass sich das nicht geändert hat. (Bin mir aber nicht sicher.)

Etwas anderes wäre es, wenn in dem Satz von **drei** Personen die Rede ist: Zwei "Burschen" und einer dritten Person, die als "der Jüngere" bezeichnet wird. Dann wäre es wirklich ein substantiviertes Adjektiv.

> Wie ist es wenn wir mehrere Adjektive verwenden?

Zum Beispiel:

> Der **i**ntelligente Jüngere war aber nicht lange da.

Das Adjektiv "intelligent" beschreibt in diesem Fall ja ein (Quasi-) Substantiv ("der Jüngere") und ist daher ein ganz normales Adjektiv...

Answer (score 0):

Hier sind ein paar Sätze, die mein Orthographenauge wohlgestalt findet:

> Ich habe zwei Burschen hier gesehen, der kleinere war aber gleich wieder weg.
>
> Kapitän Ziegenbart stieß mit Wucht die Tür zum Mannschaftsraum auf: "Wo ist der Kleine nun schon wieder?" brüllte er. Die Matrosen schauten ihn mit aufgerissenen Augen an, sagten aber nichts. Der Kleine saß in der Mehlkiste und wagte nicht, sich zu rühren.
>
> Ich habe drei Mädchen gesehen, das jüngste war das schönste.
>
> Ich habe drei Mädchen gesehen, die mittlere war die pfiffigste.
>
> Ich habe den Alten gesehen, wie er die Kinder zusammenstaucht hat.
>
> Ich habe dem elegant gekleideten Vater dreier Kinder gesagt, er soll seiner Jüngsten (oder: seiner jüngsten) und seinem Ältesten (oder: seinem ältesten) ein Eis kaufen.
>
> Ich habe dem alten Mann gesagt, er soll dem jüngsten Mädchen und dem ältesten Burschen ein Eis kaufen.
>
> Auf dem Platz waren ein alter Mann und viele Kinder. Ich habe dem alten Mann gesagt, er soll den jüngsten ein Eis, den älteren je eine Tüte Brausepulver kaufen.
>
> Auf dem Platz waren ein Mann und viele Kinder. Ich habe dem Mann gesagt, er soll dem jüngsten, blaugekleideten Kind ein Eis, dem ältesten, grüngekleideten Kind ein Wurstbrot und den anderen, schwarzgekleideten Kindern je eine Schokolade kaufen.

Comment: Diesen Satz 

„Ich habe drei Mädchen gesehen, die mittlere war die pfiffigste.“

fände mein Orthografenauge erfreulicher anzusehen, wenn „die Mittlere“ großgeschrieben wäre.